# jQuery improve table iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table containing in every row one cell inside which is checkbox and label for that checkbox.

What I'm trying to do it to hide rows based on inputed text.

Basically this is list on names and I want to filter/hide those that don't contain entered text.

This is my function:

```
$(function () {
$('#user_name').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim($('input#user_name').val()) == '') {
        $('table.myList >tbody >tr').each(function (index, value) {
            $(this).css("display", "block");
        });
    } else {
        $('table.myList >tbody >tr').each(function (index, value) {
            if ($(this).find('td > label').length > 0) {
                if ($(this).find('td > label').html().toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim($('input#user_name').val()).toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

This code works, if my table has 40 records its fast, but when I increment list to 500 it slows down and crashes my browser after time.

I'm looking for a way to improve this code to work faster.

Here is link to mock-up code: http://jsfiddle.net/gGxcS/

==UPDATE==

Here is my final solution based on answers of @scessor and @nnnnnn:

```
$(function () {

var $tableRows = $('table.myList tr');
var lastInput = '';

$('#user_name').keyup(function () {
    var sValue = $.trim($('input#user_name').val());
    if(lastInput==sValue) return;
    if (sValue == '') {
        $tableRows.show();
    } else {
        $tableRows.each(function () {
            var oLabel = $(this).find('label');
            if (oLabel.length > 0) {
                if (oLabel.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
        lastInput=sValue;
    }
});

$('img.removeSelections').click(function () {
    $('table.myList input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test this code (with lot of elements)?

```
$(function () {
    $('#user_name').keyup(function () {
        var sValue = $.trim($('input#user_name').val());
        if (sValue == '') {
            $('table.myList tr').show();
        } else {
            $('table.myList tr').each(function() {
                var jThis = $(this);
                var oLabel = jThis.find('label');
                if (oLabel.length > 0) {
                    if (oLabel.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        jThis.show();
                    } else {
                        jThis.hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

- Don't call functions with same parameters twice (e.g. `$.trim($('input#user_name').val());`).
- Use short selectors.
- Use jquery each only if necessarry (e.g. don't needed here: `$('table.myList >tbody >tr').each(function (index, value) {`).

=== UPDATE ===

If somebody holds <kbd>backspace</kbd> to long, it will set all `tr`s visible again and again. To prevent this you could check, if the last value is equal to the current value. If true, do nothing.

=== UPDATE ===

To uncheck all checkboxes, it depends on your jQuery version.

With jQuery 1.6 and higher:
`$('table.myList input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);`
Before:
`$('table.myList input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", false);`

Comment: much much much faster than mine :) Thanks :) One more question: how to deselect all checkboxes in my table? I was trying also with .each, whan I want is to add button and in on click event be able to deselect all checkboxes in my table.

Comment: @Misiu: `$('table.myList input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",false);`

Comment: I'm thinking about that check for last/current value. I must create a variable and store last value in it, then after keyup check it with current? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. At the beginning the variable (last value) is an empty string. On keypress compare it with the current value, if equal end the function, else set the 'last value' variable with the current value.

Comment: @scessor I've edited my question and added solution. I think that I've added last/current input check correct. Thanks :)

Comment: @scessor - Could You look on my second question, this is an updated version of this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613919/jquery-searchable-checkbox-list-and-tristate-checkbox

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you cache your jQuery objects - given that you want to process on every keystroke I'd cache the table rows object outside of the keyup handler. Also, don't call functions inside the `.each()` loop when you can call them once outside - e.g., no need to be calling `$.trim($('input#user_name').val()).toLowerCase()` on every `.each()` iteration.

```
$(function () {
    var $tableRows = $('table.myList >tbody >tr');

    $('#user_name').keyup(function () {
        var searchStr = $.trim($('input#user_name').val()).toLowerCase();
        if (searchStr === '') {
            $tableRows.css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $tableRows.each(function (index, value) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $label =$this.find('td > label');
                if ($label.length > 0) {
                    if ($label.html().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) >= 0) {
                        $this.css("display", "block");
                    } else {
                        $this.css("display", "none");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gGxcS/3/

Comment: idea with cache seems to be the best, but this will be inside asp webpage and I have updatepanels on it, so after some time this list can update, so then I'll have to cache them again, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the table data changes you would definitely have to update the `$tableRows` jQuery object. Given that the accepted answer worked for you without caching the `$('table.myList >tbody >tr')` object maybe you needn't bother doing that part, but if your goal is to make it as fast as possible allowing for a _lot_ of rows then I _would_ cache it.

Comment: For now I made a merged solution, Yours and @scessor's - I've added Your caching part :) this is probably the best solution, I'll check it on that asp page, how will it work with those update panels. Thank for answer and useful hints :)

Comment: maybe this is a silly question, but why $tableRows is defined with '$' at beginning and searchStr without it?

Comment: The `$` has no special meaning within JavaScript, it is simply another character that is legal for use in a variable name, but some people name variables that refer to jQuery objects with a `$` at the beginning just as a reminder that that's what those variables are for. You'll notice I did the same thing for the `$this` variable. It's an informal convention that you are free to ignore...

Comment: Could You look on my second question, this is an updated version of this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613919/jquery-searchable-checkbox-list-and-tristate-checkbox