# jQuery searchable checkbox list and tristate checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple asp page on which I have list of peoples with checkbox on left of every name.
I've managed to create a simple jQuery script that allows hiding and showing rows of table based on input:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tq97v/ (first part)

As You can see I can enter part of name and then specific row are hidden.
Using red "x" I can uncheck all checkboxes.

What I'm trying to do now is to change that static red "x" into tristate checkbox.
Don't have idea how to even start.

Do I must add change listener to every checkbox in my list?

Second thing - how to create multiple instances of the same "plugin" on site.
Right now I'm identifying input by it, but it would be nice to call function with that input as param, and it would fine table after that input and create necessary logic.
This way I could call function multiple times on page to have more than one list.

I'm not asking for whole solution (of course it is always welcome :) ) but what I need is idea how to accomplish this in efficient way and as optimized as possible, because sometimes my list has 500+ elements.

P.S. don't look at HTML code, it is ASP generated.

---

I found this plugin: https://github.com/bcollins/jquery.tristate, but  I have no idea how to use it with my list.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to turn my code into functions, but right now I must call 3 functions for every list.
Here is my updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/65MEV/4/
How can I change it to one function? Will it be better?
This is my updated code. Still thinking about way of doing that Indeterminate Checkbox instead of my remove image.

**UPDATE2**

I build working code :)
http://jsfiddle.net/65MEV/9/
But I would like to improve it as much as possible.
Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A tristate checkbox is like the Three-Portal Device: an illusion.

What you actually want is to make the checkbox `indeterminate` (by setting the property of the same name to `true`). To implement this, you will need a `change` (or `click`) handler on each checkbox, then you'll need to check if all of them are in the same state, and if not then you set the `indeterminate` property. It's a hassle, really, because you rarely see `indeterminate` checkboxes and so most users don't know what to do with them. To be avoided, if possible.

Comment: This is an option, but my solution must work in IE7. Sorry I didn't mention it in my question. So I think that using images will be easer-it will work in old browsers.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check it, just found entry on some blog, now is is confirmed :) I've updated my question so I can have multiple lists on one site, but still I have problem with that checkbox.

Comment: Perhaps you could enclose each "group" inside an element with a given className, and then simply use `$(".myclass").each()` to call the necessary functions?

Comment: I've updated my question again, this time I've added working example of what I'm trying to do. This works, but I would like to optimize it. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple instances of the same plugin access elements relatively to an other element.

For example: in your case instead of keeping the item in a jQuery object `var $tableRows = $('table.myList tr');` access them in the event.

```
$('#user_name').keyup(function () {
    var sValue = $.trim($('input#user_name').val());
    if(lastInput==sValue) return;
    var $tableRows = $(this).next().next().find("table.myList tr");
    if (sValue == '') {
        $tableRows.show();
    } else {
        $tableRows.each(function () {
            var oLabel = $(this).find('label');
            if (oLabel.length > 0) {
                if (oLabel.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
        lastInput=sValue;
    }
});
```

and you only have your actual list.

And for the tree state checkbox you don t need a plugin just add a button or link and every click check it status you can keep the status by [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and change the element image according to this data.

Comment: I've kept elements in object to speed up my code. This way elements are stored just ones. If I would do it your way list holding all tr elements would be created every time I press key inside input. This works fine for 50 elements, but when I have 500+ elements and old pc this slows down.

Comment: I've updated my question with functional approach, but I'm always opened for suggestions :) Especially with that Indeterminate checkbox.